# I am unable to resolve the below problem. This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server observed on IE with different localhost and port number shown on my screen.

I have put my code sample below. Please help me out.

- IE version: 11 (32 bit)
- Selenium IE Webdriver : 3.141.5.0 (32 bit)
- C# language

I tried solutions given in stack overflow by Enabling all protected zones.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    string url = @"http://www.google.com";

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Console.WriteLine("Ending");
    driver.Quit();
}
```

It is expected to open google.com. But shows me This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have downloaded the "IEDriverServer.exe" first, then, you could use the following code to use the webdriver:

```
private const string URL = @"http://www.google.com";
// DriverServer path. You could download the server from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html. then get the path.
private const string IE_DRIVER_PATH = @"D:\Downloads\webdriver\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0";
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
    {
        InitialBrowserUrl = URL,
        IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true
    };
    var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, options);
    driver.Navigate();
    driver.Close(); // closes browser
    driver.Quit(); // closes IEDriverServer process

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I am observing a new error. I tried the solutions online, did not help.
An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Comment: Try to use "Manage Nuget Packages..." options to install the WebDriver, result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yCo9.png).

Answer (score 0):

The selenium webdriver was not compatible with the browser. It needed re-installation of the webdriver to match browser. It works fine now.